# pragma pack an stl containers

Tags: c++, stl, memory-alignment

When I declare such a structure:

```
#pragma pack(1)
structure MyStruct{
    uint32_t first;
    uint8_t second;
};
#pragma pack()
```

I obviously wish it will take 5 bytes of memory. How will then such a vector behaves:

```
std::vector<MyStruct> MyVec;
```

Or such a map:

```
std::map<MyStruct> MyMap;
```

Will they obey requested alignment? Can I force STL structures to do that?

Comment: Are you talking about packing the internal data of the stl containers or a struct containing stl containers?

Comment: Packing the internal data. I wish MyVec or MyMap to be as small as it is possible.

Answer (score 5):

With the proviso that some compiler could ignore the `#pragma` completely, yes, the `#pragma`  affects the definition of the type, so storing that type in a vector (for example) means what's stored will be packed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned long uint32_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

struct MyStruct0{
    uint32_t first;
    uint8_t second;
};

#pragma pack(1)
struct MyStruct{
    uint32_t first;
    uint8_t second;
};
#pragma pack()

int main(){ 
    std::vector<MyStruct0> a;

    std::vector<MyStruct> b;

    std::cout << "Unpacked size: " << sizeof(a[0]) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Packed size: " << sizeof(b[0]) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Unpacked size: 8
Packed size: 5
```

Comment: IMO you should better show byte difference of b[1] - b[0], the sizeof is based on just types...

Comment: it also requires a[0] use value_type and value_type be the template param... :)

Comment: I think there is a stronger example for the std::vector case:

`MyStruct0 ms0_array[2];`
`MyStruct ms_array[2];`

`std::cout << "Unpacked array: " << sizeof(ms0_array) << std::endl;`
`std::cout << "Packed array: " << sizeof(ms_array) << std::endl;`

You should also be aware turning packing on can cause slower access to the data.

Answer (score 5):

std::vector is required to be layout-compatible with plain C=style array of the same type. So it has no choice but place them at the size you managed for the struct.

For other, node-based collections it is up to the implementation how the nodes are created, what extra bytes appear there.

Answer (score 1):

Is size *really* an issue here? Sounds like premature optimization.

In any case, for `std::vector` it usually (implementation dependant) contains 2 member variables: it's size and a pointer to the data. So unless you have a LOT of them, packing isn't going to change much (and before you ask packing the data wouldn't affect anything because it's a continuous chunk of memory anyway, because it has to be compatible with C).

For map, I'm less sure of it's internal structure but again packing would probably not affect much as IIRC it's often implemented as a balanced tree. So again, unless you have a lot lot lot of them, not much to gain here.

Edit: Also, I've popped open the MSVC vector header and there seem to be instructions to ignore pragma packing (namely a pragma push at the top of the file and a pragma pop at the bottom).

Comment: As far as I know std::vector usually has 3 member variables, size, pointer to data, and capacity. And unfortunately I have to play with vectors, which takes up to several GB of memory.

Comment: Do you have multiple vectors which add up to GB of memory of just a few big ones? If it's the latter packing the struct will do 99% of the work.

Comment: Multiple and due to this I'm looking for any kind of memory optimization.